# Nondegenerate pairings versus perfect pairings for finitely generated projective modules

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a (not necessarily commutative) ring, $M$ a left $R$-module, and $N$ a right $R$-module. We say that a pairing
$$
\langle -,-\rangle:M \otimes_R N \to R
$$
is non-degenerate if, for all $n \in N$ there exists an $m \in M$ such that $\langle m,n\rangle \neq 0$, \textbf{and} for all $m \in M$, there exists an $n \in N$ such that $\langle m,n\rangle \neq 0$.

Such a pairing will give embeddings
$$
M \hookrightarrow N^*,  ~~~~~ N \hookrightarrow M^*,
$$
where $M^*$ and $N^*$ denote the dual modules of $M$ and $N$ respectively. In general (even for infinite-dimensional vector spaces) this will not give isomorphisms
$$
N \simeq M^*, ~~~~ M \simeq N^*.
$$
However, if we assume that $M$ and $N$ are finitely-generalted projective, then does non-degeneracy imply that we get isomorphisms?

If it fails in the general noncommutative setting, I would still be interested in a positive answer in the commutative setting.

Comment: In general $M, N$ need not even be abstractly isomorphic. For example, *any* two rank one projective modules over a ring admit a non-degenerate pairing, as such a pairing is the same as a nonzero element of $(M\otimes N)^\vee$.

Comment: Just take $R = M = N = \mathbb{Z}$ and $\langle m, n \rangle = 2mn$.

Comment: @Najib: Excellent example! This illustrates exactly what goes wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No: for $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and even for $M,N$ both free (i.e. free Abelian groups), non-degenerate doesn't imply perfect. (You get finite index sublattices, so torsion quotients, unlike the case of vector spaces.)

Comment: By an odd coincidence, I've spent the last few weeks in exactly this situation, and mildly grumpy that this isn't true as it would save a pile of work...

Comment: Even for $R = \mathbb{Z}$ . . . I didn't know life was so cruel.

Comment: Could you please provide a reference for this?

Comment: No I can't sorry.  I struggled to find this set out anywhere - it took a bit of digging even to turn up that non-degenerate and perfect were the right terminology.